# How to change the NSPopover's arrow head position?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, popover

I have a NSPopover on my app but i want to change the position of the arrow head.

What i have: 
[image]

What i want:
[image]

As you can see in the second image the arrow head of the NSPopover is at the top.
How can i do that?

my code:

```
[_popover showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxXEdge];
```

Thank you!

Comment: How did you get the second screenshot? :)

Comment: just dragged my window to the top and the popover does that automatically

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible with `NSPopover` (as of 10.7).  You'll have to use an alternative popover, such as the excellent [`SFBPopovers`](https://github.com/sbooth/SFBPopovers).

Comment: Not a problem! Hopefully Apple will add more options in later versions of their OS.