# NSPopover pointer always centered

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nspopover

NSPopover pointer gets always placed on the center, creating a bad effect when the button is placed in a corner.

Is there a way in Swift I can move the pointer to left or right???

I know this same problem was questioned a while ago, just wondering if there is any update.

Thanks in advance,

Juan

Comment: @ZGski this question is about OS X, not iOS

Comment: I think, centering of the PO is done to minimize the average mouse distance. What is wrong with that?

Comment: @ Amin Negm-Awad, is not the end of the world, but some times aesthetically you don't want to go out of frame margins or hide some text.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this still seems to be not possible, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10767008/4113940) still seems to apply.

File a radar for Apple, as well as I am going to do. Then we might get the feature one day.

Comment: I saw that post but being 4 years old I was hoping  it could be fixed now. Thanks.